# Using same keys in different properties files with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

Let say I have two properties files:

**prop1.properties**

```
name=foo
```

**prop2.properties**

```
name=bar
```

I want to inject those properties into two different classes using [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html). My current approach is:

**Foo.java**

```
@Component
@PropertySource("prop1.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Foo {

    private String name;

    // Getter & setter
}
```

**Bar.java**

```
@Component
@PropertySource("prop2.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Bar {

    private String name;

    // Getter & setter
}
```

When I am testing it, I am getting name `bar` in both classes, which means both classes are looking for all properties files defined on every `@PropertySource` and `prop2.properties` file takes precedence. I'm aware that there's solution by adding prefix on the keys, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: Did you solve this? Im facing the same problem